# PHP echo elseif inside of a selectbox on <option>. Issue

Tags: php

I'm trying to use `if` and `elseif` on a `<option>` tag but I only got errors and can't manage to solve it.

```
 <span class="label" id="parcela-pad">Ou em até:</span><select id="parcelaonhover-pt-be">
 <!-- sem juros: --> 

<?php
  $_product = $this->getProduct();
  // máximo de parcelas
  $maxParcelas = 12;
  // valor minimo de cada parcela
  $valorMinimo = 15;
  $taxa = 0;
  $valorParcela_br = $capital;
  $capital = $_product->getFinalPrice();
  $numParcelas = getNumParcelas($capital, $maxParcelas, $valorMinimo);
  for($i=1; $i <= $numParcelas; $i++){
      $valorParcela = getValorParcela($capital, $i+1, $taxa);
      //boleto inicio
      //$_product = $this->getProduct();
      //$total = $_product->getFinalPrice(); // initial value
      $percent = '10'; // without %
      $discount_value = ($capital / 100) * $percent;
      $final_price = $capital - $discount_value;
?>
```

Below is my PHP code that is not working and breaking my page. I did put my echo on {}

```
<?php

 if($valorMinimo>$valorParcela){
     echo <option selected disabled>a vista </option>
 } elseif($valorMinimo<$valorParcela){
     echo <option selected disabled>Parcelamento no cartão de crédito:</option>
 } ?>
```

So can I get some tips ?

Thanks!

Comment: is that a typo? or your echo statement are missing a quotation?

Comment: it was a typo, sorry. but still not working with quotation.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
echo '<option selected disabled>Parcelamento no cartão de crédito:</option>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you a more readable way to embed php into html:

```
<?php if($valorMinimo > $valorParcela): ?>
    <option selected disabled>a vista </option>
<?php elseif($valorMinimo < $valorParcela): ?>
    <option selected disabled>Parcelamento no cartão de crédito:</option>
<?php endif; ?>
```